# how to fix WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'

Tags: android, build.gradle

it is a simple hello world application. when i did not connected my project to firebase it was working well. but ever since i connected my connected to firebase and add set up the dependencies it is showing

> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

and here is my `build.gradle` code:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hfad.testauto2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Probably a dependency you are using still has `compile`.

Comment: as you can see there is no compile in dependencies

Comment: I meant a library has it in their build.gradle.

Comment: can you  create hello world app and connect it to firebase as i have done in my app. it would be great help for me. and if you able to solve that error please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Add classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' in project: build.gradle dependencies.

Comment: i did as you said now it is showing this Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services:3.2.0' not found.

Comment: Add classpath com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0 dependencies at project level build.gradle not app gradle

Comment: still getting the error but this it showing this org.gradle.api.GradleException: File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
 Searched Location:

Comment: Try Upgrading Your Android Studio to latest version and apply the above class path

Comment: You need to get the configuration file from the developer's site and paste it in the app level directory of your project.